# chrome autocomplete breaks styled selects

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, autocomplete

I've got a styled select box that works just fine in all browsers. Here's the CSS (which incorporates a lot of different styling to handle the various browsers):

```
select {
    background-image: url(../img/dropdown.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right center;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
    padding-right: 36px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    -ms-border-radius: 0;
    -o-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-right: none;
    border-color: #9da6ab;
    color: #36495a;
    display: inline-block;
    outline: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 28px;
    padding: 5px 36px 6px 1px;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -moz-appearance:none;
    text-indent: 0.01px;
    text-overflow: '';
}

select::-ms-expand {
    display:none;
}

html.lt-ie10 select {
    background-image:none;
    height:32px;
    padding-right: 6px;
    border-right: 1px solid;
}
```

When Chrome autocompletes my form (which is your standard-issue name, address, country, and credit card info form), any field that is autopopulated gets that pale yellow background color. The problem is, however it does this manages to hide my `background-image` directive. The dropdown image comes right back if I scroll the page, or click in any field.

before:

[image: Before Autocomplete]

after:

[image: After Autocomplete]

My first thought was that I just needed to give the selects a `position:relative` and a `z-index` but that didn't change anything. I suppose I could try to disable autocomplete, but that degrades the user's expected experience. Then I thought setting `!important` on the background image would do it, seeing as Chrome was probably applying a stylesheet to it that was overriding my image temporarily. Nada. Setting the focus on another field (or the same field) via jQuery doesn't work (at least it didn't in the developer tools console). A super ugly hack would be to catch that autocomplete event (if possible; and no, I'm not installing jQueryUI just for this) and then using `window.scrollBy(0,1);window.scrollBy(0,-1)` to quickly scroll up and down, which repaints the controls without forcing a full css refresh (and, based on console testing, doesn't actually appear to move the screen). But I can't figure out how to catch the autocomplete event and I'd rather not fire that on every blur...and  even if I did do it on blur, it still doesn't solve the fact that the mere act of showing the autocomplete dropdown brings up that yellow background and breaks the styling.

Is there something in my CSS that is causing this to happen? Or do I have to rely on Javascript to compensate for Chrome's stupidity here?

Comment: Look at this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27987624/changing-input-background-for-chrome-autocomplete#42899873, it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of the yellow background using:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("chrome") >= 0) {
$(window).load(function(){
    $('input:-webkit-autofill').each(function(){
        var text = $(this).val();
        var name = $(this).attr('name');
        $(this).after(this.outerHTML).remove();
        $('input[name=' + name + ']').val(text);
    });
});
}
```

Comment: Adding this code had no discernible effect on the issue. In fact, debugging the console, it appears it never runs. The if block works; the jquery selector returns controls; but a breakpoint inside the `.each()` function was never hit. And in any case, the yellow background isn't strictly the problem; it's the fact that my select arrows disappear during the autocomplete process and don't reappear unless the screen is repainted.